# How to provide reference to auto-generated documenation from Composer?

Tags: php, documentation, composer-php

I would like to add a documentation link to the `composer.json`.
I know you can use "homepage" for adding a link to the website, but is there any entry I can use for adding a link to the documentation, e.g. to one created with phpDocumentor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It can be included under the `support` root-level key:

```
{
    "support": {
        "docs": "http://docs.org",
    }
}
```

More information about composers.json's schema can be found on [getcomposer.org](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#support)